# PHP post form hidden input

Tags: php, http, hidden-field

I have a form

```
<form class="well form-search" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="add"/>
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="User name" />
    <input type="password" name="passwd" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Add User</button>
</form>
```

'uname' and 'passwd' end up in $_POST but 'act' is in $_GET for some reason.

Comment: ??? Really? I find that kind of hard to believe.

Comment: Is it available in both $_GET and $_POST or solely $_GET

Comment: Does your URL have `?act=value` in it?

Comment: Just in $_GET, nope, no ?act=add. Xdebug can't be lying, right?

Comment: Based on your code sample above, that's impossible.

Comment: Seems that Xdebug browned out. Restarted, all working as expected.

Comment: What is output of echo $_POST['act']?